# Adding Row to datatable in dataset

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, datarow

I am trying to copy a row from one table to another in same dataset. 
code I am using

```
dsFrom.Tables["asd2"].Rows.Add(dsFrom.Tables["asd"].Rows[0].ItemArray);
```

I am getting an NullRefferenceException. I've determined that Rows are null, even though there is data in both tables. Can anyone explain why is this happening? Or maybe there is another solution for my problem.

Thanks

**EDIT**
This is how I am loading data in them

```
string query = @"select * from table1;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
                DataSet dsFrom = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(dsFrom, "asd");
                da.Fill(dsFrom, "asd2");
```

Comment: Can you show some more code like the loading of data in these data tables.

Comment: @PraveenPaulose I've added edit with how I am loading data.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try to copy rows by this way:

```
foreach (var row in dsFrom.Tables["asd"].Rows)
{
     dsFrom.Tables["asd2"].ImportRow(row);
}
```